# Linear regression and model comparison with grouped data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, regression, tidyr

I am testing different linear regression models for data that can be grouped (`grp1` and `grp2`).

```
library(rcompanion)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
  
#some sample data
sampleDF <- data.frame(grp1=append(rep("foo",6),rep("bar",6)), 
                       grp2=append(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)), 
                       x=seq(3)-rnorm(3), 
                       y=seq(3)*3+1)

#some models
model1 <- y ~ x
model2 <- y ~ x - 1

#do the fitting
sampleDF %>%
  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>% 
  do(model1 = lm(model1, data = .),
     model2 = lm(model2, data = .)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> fittedModels
```

This yields:

```
 fittedModels
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  grp1  grp2  model1 model2
* <fct> <fct> <list> <list>
1 bar   A     <lm>   <lm>  
2 bar   B     <lm>   <lm>  
3 foo   A     <lm>   <lm>  
4 foo   B     <lm>   <lm>
```

Using `broom` the models can be nicely gathered into data frames, like:

```
fittedModels %>% rowwise() %>% broom::tidy(model2)

# A tibble: 4 x 7
# Groups:   grp1, grp2 [4]
  grp1  grp2  term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <fct> <fct> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 bar   A     x         3.43     0.124      27.7 0.00130
2 bar   B     x         3.43     0.124      27.7 0.00130
3 foo   A     x         3.43     0.124      27.7 0.00130
4 foo   B     x         3.43     0.124      27.7 0.00130
```

I would like compare the models using different approaches. The library `rcompanion` provides the methods `compareLM()` and `pairwiseModelAnova()`.

Trying:

```
fittedModels %>% summarise(compareLM(model1, model2))
> Error in formula.default(fits[[i]]) : invalid formula

rowwise(fittedModels) %>% summarise(compareLM(model1, model2))
> Error: Column `compareLM(model1, model2)` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

Closer inspections reveals:

```
fittedModels$model1[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
          0            3  

m.1 <- fittedModels$model1[1]
m.2 <- fittedModels$model2[1]
compareLM(m.1,m.2)
> Error in formula.default(fits[[i]]) : invalid formula
```

Which might point to an issue with piping?!

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtain an error with your data, but it works when a random number is added to `sampleDF$x`.

```
library(rcompanion)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)

#some sample data
set.seed(1)
sampleDF <- data.frame(grp1=append(rep("foo",6),rep("bar",6)), 
                       grp2=append(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)), 
                       x=seq(3) - rnorm(3), 
                       y=seq(3)*3+1)

#some models
model1 <- y ~ x
model2 <- y ~ x - 1

# Use purrr
sampleDF %>%
  group_by(grp1, grp2) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model1 = purrr::map(data, ~lm(model1, data = .))) %>%
  mutate(model2 = purrr::map(data, ~lm(model2, data = .))) %>%
  mutate(tidy_model1 = purrr::map(model1, broom::tidy)) %>%
  mutate(tidy_model2 = purrr::map(model2, broom::tidy)) %>%
  mutate(compare_m1m2 = purrr::map2(model1, model2, ~compareLM(.x, .y)))

> # A tibble: 4 x 8
> # Groups:   grp1, grp2 [4]
> grp1  grp2  data             model1 model2 tidy_model1      tidy_model2      > compare_m1m2    
> <chr> <chr> <list>           <list> <list> <list>           <list>           > <list>          
> 1 foo   A     <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>   <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 5]> <named list [2]>
> 2 foo   B     <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>   <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 5]> <named list [2]>
> 3 bar   A     <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>   <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 5]> <named list [2]>
> 4 bar   B     <tibble [3 × 2]> <lm>   <lm>   <tibble [2 × 5]> <tibble [1 × 5]> <named list [2]>
```

Comment: Great use of `purrr` the problem here is only that one cannot unnest() the `model1` and `model2` columns.

Comment: Yes, the columns model1 and model2 cannot be combined to a single data frame. Of course you can choose to only unnest the other columns